# How do I prevent concurrent inserts from creating duplicate items?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, celery

I have a SQLAlchemy model object that looks like this:

```
ResultModelBase = declarative_base()
class Task(ResultModelBase):
    """Task result/status."""

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.Sequence("task_id_sequence"),
                   primary_key=True,
                   autoincrement=True)
    task_id = sa.Column(sa.String(255))
```

In two separate client processes, this code is being run to create a new instance with a unique task_id; there must be only one instance of a task_id:

```
task = session.query(Task).filter(Task.task_id == task_id).first()
if not task:
    task = Task(task_id)
    session.add(task)
    session.flush()
```

How can I rewrite this code so that it atomically creates a task with the specified ID?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is ill-defined. You have a design flaw in your database. You can not define the uniqueness of the row by its auto-incrementing id. You must have other fields that define it as unique (e.g. task_name+worker), and then create the task by these fields: `Task(task_name=smt, worker=smt)` - do not put `task_id` manually - it will be assigned as the next table-id automatically. Use the autoinc primary keys only for look-up and relationships - but *always* put a unique key composed from other tables. If you can not figure out which fields - than your table is not normalized.

Now, for the problem of handling insertion of duplicates:
session.flush() # executes the previous work

```
session.flush()
try: 
    t = Task(task_name=smt, worker=smt)
    session.add()
    session.flush()
except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
    # task already exists 
else:
    # task added to db
```

Comment: Yeah, adding a constraint in the DB is definitely the right way. The `task_id` should be declared unique (and should have a index too for speed): `task_id = sa.Column(sa.String(255), unique=True, index=True)`

Comment: @THC4k: `unique=True` is to create unique index, so `index=True` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Use locks around the block of code.

```
# lock here
task = session.query(Task).filter(Task.task_id == task_id).first()
if not task:
    task = Task(task_id)
    session.add(task)
    session.flush()
# unlock here
```

Comment: I'd prefer something more practical than that; for one, lock on what?